# How should I use attributes on the "through" object in a has_many: through: ActiveRecord relation?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

```rb
class Reservation << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :charges_reservations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :charges, :through => :charges_reservations
  monetize :price_cents
  
  def associate_charge(charge, portion)
    # looking for help here
  end
  
  def owing
    price - amount_paid
  end
  
  def amount_paid
    # looking for help here
  end
end

class ChargesReservation << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :charge
  belongs_to :reservation

  monetize :portion_cents
end

class Charge << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :charges_reservations
  has_many :reservations, :through => :charges_reservations

  monetize :amount_cents

  validates :state, inclusion: {in: %w(failed successful pending)}

  def successful?
    state == "successful"
  end
end
```

What I want to know is, how to access the portion attribute on
`ChargesReservation` both when associating the charges with the reservations,
and when asking whether the reservation is fully paid. Both `Charge` and
`Reservation` are created at different points in the user flow.

So my question is twofold:

- what's the best way to create the association once I have a charge?
- how do I get the sum of a reservation's portions of all successful charges
  associated with it, *as a model method*. I know, roughly, how to achieve this
  in SQL (I'm rusty, but I'd get there) but I'm stumped in ActiveRecord.

Comment: What is the expected type of `portion`? Confused as to what that is being associated with. Follow-up: why does the association call need to be in the model, instead of whatever service is creating the charge?

Comment: `portion` will be a `Money` object derived via the `monetize` helper from `:portion_cents`. And the act of creating the association can be in the controller, but once it's there it's necessary to access it from one or the other side.